# Testing performance using %%timeit, loop speed or total time elapsed more important?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm iterating csv files with 10k-100k rows millions of times so performance is of crucial importance. I'm going line by line optimizing every line to squeeze every fraction of a second. This is simple just cloning one dataframe series. Currently confused with these initial results.

```py
    @numba.jit()
    def test(x):
        return x

    #%%timeit
    df['source'] = df['Close']
    #79.5 µs ± 3.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

    #%%timeit
    df['source2'] = test(df['Close'].to_numpy())
    #88.1 µs ± 683 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The overall elapsed time is faster in the first, but the per loop is faster in the second. If the per loop is faster, I would expect it to be faster overall.

Does this mean that there is that much more time being utilized in the back end? Can someone explain this to me.

Should I give more importance to the total elapsed time or the per loop time?

Note, I'm using Jupyter notebook on Anaconda.

Comment: Where is the total elapsed time in your output?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the wording. It's "79.5 µs ± 3.58 µs" per loop, not 79.5 µs overall and 3.58 µs per loop. What you're seeing is that the second one has a smaller variance in speed, it's still slower though.

Comment: `79.5 µs ± 3.58 µs per loop` means that it took on average 79.5 micro seconds with a standard deviation of 3.58 micro seconds.  That means that ~65% percent of the runs were within the interval of 76 to 83 micro seconds.  On the other hand `88.1 µs ± 683 ns` means that with an average of 88.1 micro seconds and a standard deviation of 683 nano seconds, ~65% of the trials were within the interval of 87.4 to 88.8 micro seconds.  This implies that with roughly the same average the numba pass through is much more consistent.

Comment: Could you also post the total times of your loops? I interpret the times you posted as per loop times. Or maybe just explain more what you mean by per loop and total times.

Comment: @ALollz. On mark, yes, I misunderstood it.

Comment: @piRSquared, thanks for the thorough explanation. I know fully understand this.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of only one thing that is different for total time and iteration time. This is a garbage collection. Python's garbage collector from time to time checks what variables are not used anymore and frees the memory for them. If you run one loop you probably will never see it working. But if it runs for a long time than most likely it is triggered and starts freeing memory, which takes time. Therefore if there was much more memory allocated during the loop the garbage collector needs more time to free the memory.

This thinking leads to one possible improvement to you code:
Be mindful how much you allocate memory.

`df['source'] = df['Close']` could mean that you copy your data from one column to another. Try to reuse data as much as possible. For example, do `col1 = df['Close']` and then use `col1` for further manipulations. This way the data is not copied and it is faster (in case you do not need column `source` and it is used temporarily).

There is also another possibility to speed up things by not allocating and deallocating memory. When using Numba, it is faster to iterate over all rows and do calculations in one go instead of iterating over the same data multiple times when you use vector formulas of Numpy/Pandas. You not only save on iterating on data multiple times, but can even use stack variables instead of heap (terminology only relevant to compiled code. Python stores everything in the heap). By using stack variables in Numba you essentially stop allocating and deallocating memory constantly.

Another option could be to preallocate variables before the big loop and reuse them for every itaration of the loop. But this only helps if you have stable variable size for each iteration (meaning number of rows for each CSV file in your case)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, because the total time isn't reported. The OP was just confused about the st. dev

Comment: @user1558604 The OP said that the total time did not correspond to the in the loop time. I interpreted that he was talking about averages and not about standard deviation. The reason explained here is the only one I can think that could explain why total time is smaller, but in the loop time is bigger compared to the other alternative. He never mentioned st. dev in the question

Comment: The times OP posted in the question are loop times. There were no total times posted and the comments on the post seem to indicate that the OP misinterpretted the standard deviation as the loop time, when that isn't the case.